# Execute Java via CMD, with error "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

Tags: java

I've got a script that requires a driver, and performs a few selects to a DB for quality purposes. Well, this script "dbquality.jar" is executed with this:

> java -Xmx1024m -jar dbquality.jar

... but it throws:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassDriverVersionError dbquality/Dbquality :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

How can I fix it? If possible, without needing to re-compile the file. If there is no more option, tell me how can I fix it. I think that both computers got the JDK 7, but I may be wrong. This computer (the script executer) does have it; will check later if the compiler computer also does.

Some help here!

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I found some information regarding that problem, but I'm trying to find a client-side solution!

Comment: `52.0` means that your code has been compiled with Java 8 while you are trying to execute it with Java 7, you need to upgrade to Java 8 or recompile with Java 7

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thank you! You can post it as an answer and I will accept it, since that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Thx but FYI when a question is closed no one can answer which is actually the purpose of closing an issue